# Connection to server refused (running docker failing)

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

I have a Python script that extracts data from an API, saves it to a DB. Then, it gets data from a view in that same DB and sends it by email as an excel file.

I was able to build a `docker-compose.yaml` file that correctly starts a PostgreSQL DB instance and Adminer.

Now, I was trying to set up my Python script as another service and I am using a `Dockerfile` to do that.

When I start my container I get the below error message (truncated for simplicity):

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "0.0.0.0", port 5432 failed: Connection refused
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

This is my `docker-compose.yaml file`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.3
    container_name: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
      - POSTGRES_DB=dbname
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  adminer:
    image: adminer:4.8.1
    container_name: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8077:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes:
  db_data:
```

And, this is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-buster

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy requirements file to work directory
COPY pyproject.toml pyproject.toml
COPY poetry.lock poetry.lock

# install poetry
RUN pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install poetry

# install dependencies
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

# add source code to the image
COPY src src

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "src/main.py" ]
```

I am working on this project using Github Codespaces, so I am uncertain if that could somehow affect. Also, below is my project structure:

```
> myproject
    > src
        > __init__.py
        > settings.py
        > main.py
        > utils.py
    > docker-compose.yaml
    > Dockerfile
    > init.sql
    > poetry.lock
    > pyproject.toml
    > README.md
```

Please help me fix this issue and also understand what I did wrong. I've been searching online for an answer for over 2 days, but so far nothing.

I am using the same host and port that my PostgreSQL instance is running on, but that still did not fix the issue.

The script runs well when I simply do `python src/main.py`.

**Edit # 1**:

```
def db_connection():
    """ Create SQL engine. """
    conn = f'postgresql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PW}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}'
    engine = create_engine(conn)
    return engine
```

This is the function I am using to create the SQL engine.

```
DB_HOST = "0.0.0.0"
DB_PORT = "5432"
```

**Edit #2**
I applied the changes recommended, but it's still not working. Some logs:

```
    app_1      | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1      |   File "/app/src/main.py", line 60, in <module>
app_1      |     main()
app_1      |   File "/app/src/main.py", line 54, in main
app_1      |     csv_data = get_filtered_data(engine, '...')
app_1      |   File "/app/src/utils.py", line 45, in get_filtered_data
app_1      |     with engine.connect() as conn:
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3251, in connect
app_1      |     return self._connection_cls(self)
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 147, in __init__
app_1      |     Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2413, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
app_1      |     raise sqlalchemy_exception.with_traceback(exc_info[2]) from e
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 145, in __init__
app_1      |     self._dbapi_connection = engine.raw_connection()
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3275, in raw_connection
app_1      |     return self.pool.connect()
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 455, in connect
app_1      |     return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 1271, in _checkout
app_1      |     fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 719, in checkout
app_1      |     rec = pool._do_get()
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 168, in _do_get
app_1      |     with util.safe_reraise():
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
app_1      |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 166, in _do_get
app_1      |     return self._create_connection()
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 396, in _create_connection
app_1      |     return _ConnectionRecord(self)
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 681, in __init__
app_1      |     self.__connect()
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 905, in __connect
app_1      |     with util.safe_reraise():
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 147, in __exit__
app_1      |     raise exc_value.with_traceback(exc_tb)
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 901, in __connect
app_1      |     self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 636, in connect
app_1      |     return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 580, in connect
app_1      |     return self.loaded_dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
app_1      |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
app_1      |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
app_1      | sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "172.23.0.2", port 5432 failed: Connection timed out
app_1      |    Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
app_1      | 
app_1      | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Comment: use database host  from environment variable it will fix the issue, modify your code to use this environment variable

Comment: You need to share your code, but do not use `localhost:5432` or `0.0.0.0:5432` in your Python code

Comment: I have updated my question to include the part of the code trying to connect to DB. @OneCricketeer, those were the exact values I am using. What is the reason I shouldn't use those? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I believe from your compose file your host should be `postgres` the name of your db container.

Comment: This isn't really a Python problem. Refer [networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/), which has this exact example

Comment: @JonSG I updated my host variable as such `DB_HOST = 'postgres'`, but when I ran it failed again:  `could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known `

Comment: @JonSG `links` is deprecated. Compose starts a local network, by default with DNS resolvable between services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your environment variables in the compose file and connect to a routable host (0.0.0.0 is not)

```
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_HOST: postgres  # matches 'container_name' of db container
      DB_PORT: "5432"
```

Then ensure you are using something like

```py
db_address = f'{os.environ.get("DB_HOST")}:{os.environ.get("DB_PORT")}'
```

Comment: As mentioned, that is not necessary

Comment: cool, thanks for the heads up about depreciation of `links`.

Comment: Actually, `--links` on `docker run` is deprecated. I see in the Compose docs, `links:` section is for aliasing a service to another name, but I think `container_name` on the other service will do the same

Comment: @OneCricketeer I applied the changes you did and the host/port did change in the error log, but the same is still happening. :/

Comment: @pipoca Since I don't have your source code, I cannot reproduce, but I know when I've used mysql, for example, then I've need to add SQL commands to grant user connections in order to connect. It's also not clear where you're supplying username and password

Comment: @OneCricketeer if you feel comfortable, I can share with you my github repo. I'm really lost with this issue!

Comment: Can you create a new post with your src python files and new error? And just mention you're trying to connect to a docker Postgres instance in Docker compose?